# Who is the location services provider for Safari on iOS and desktop

Tags: ios, safari, geolocation, google-search

it seems that Google Location Services is the location services provider for Firefox and Chrome. I have not been able to find any information about who is the location services provider for iOS and Mac's Safari browser.  I don't want to just assume Google, although I'm guessing it probably is.

Does anyone know, and have a pointer to Apple's documentation on this? Most browsers have a privacy policy regarding location and I haven't been able to find this for Safari either.  This page doesn't say who the provider is: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1975, and neither does their privacy policy: http://www.apple.com/privacy/.

Comment: If used with an iPad having a GPS on the device, does it use the coordinates from the GPS or one of these location services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple.

They use crowd-sourced Wi-Fi/cell tower info database (probably shared with Skyhook as they have previously recommended people to update Skyhook if something is inaccurate).

GPS is GPS.

http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/04/27location_qa.html

Hope this helps.